# Where is the Java Jar icon located?

Tags: java, icons, dll, jar

I'm trying to find what dll or folder the jar icon for Java is located in. it looks like

[image: jar file]

I'm referring to the complete icon you see in the picture, complete with the paper backing.

I've already tried using [IconsExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html) on my entire Java directory, but was unable to find it, and googling brought me nothing.

If someone could show me where this file is located, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's just contained inside the `java.exe` , but also in many other executables.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm looking for the entire icon you see in my original post, complete with the paper backing.

Comment: @Starwarswii The paper background is something that windows generates automatically. It's not really anywhere inside an icon file. Windows does this to distinguish the icon of the executable from the one of its files/documents. It's a kind of overlay trick.

Comment: is there anyway I can construct an icon that has the paper background?

Comment: The basic windows icons are contained inside the `c:\windows\system32\imageres.dll`and `c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll` files. The paper background is probably inside one of them. So you could extract that icon as well. Next you could merge the 2 icons using an icon merge tool. Yes, it will be a lot of work for something simple. But I don't think there's another way.